# PyFlink UDAF InternalRow vs. Row

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to call an outer function through custom UDAF in `PyFlink`. The function I use requires the data to be in a dictionary object. I tried to use `row(t.rowtime, t.b, t.c).cast(schema)` to achieve such effect.

Outside the UDAF, this expression works well. Inside the UDAF, this expression is translated to `InternalRow` which cannot be converted into a dictionary object.

Is there a way to force UDAF to use `Row` instead of `InternalRow`?

```py
from pyflink.common import Row
from pyflink.table import EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment, AggregateFunction, DataTypes
from pyflink.table.expressions import row, col, lit, row_interval
from pyflink.table.window import Tumble
from pyflink.table.udf import udaf

from datetime import datetime, date, time

class TestAccumulator(AggregateFunction):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return Row(last_type="")

    def accumulate(self, accumulator, value):
        accumulator["last_type"] = str(type(value))

    def get_value(self, accumulator):
        return accumulator["last_type"]

    def get_result_type(self):
        return DataTypes.STRING()

    def get_accumulator_type(self):
        return DataTypes.ROW([
            DataTypes.FIELD("last_type", DataTypes.STRING()),
        ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a blink streaming TableEnvironment
    env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
    table_env = TableEnvironment.create(env_settings)

    schema = DataTypes.ROW([
        DataTypes.FIELD("rowtime", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)),
        DataTypes.FIELD("b", DataTypes.STRING()),
        DataTypes.FIELD("c", DataTypes.STRING()),
        ])


    my_udaf = udaf(TestAccumulator())

    t = table_env.from_elements([(datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 'Hi', 'Hello'),
                                 (datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'Hi', 'hi'),
                                 (datetime(1970, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0), 'Hi2', 'hi'),
                                 (datetime(1970, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0), 'Hi', 'Hello'),
                                 (datetime(1970, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0), 'Hi', 'Hello')], schema=schema)

    print(
        t.select( my_udaf(row(t.rowtime, t.b, t.c).cast(schema)).alias("udaf")).to_pandas().values
    )
```

Output:

```
[["<class 'pyflink.fn_execution.coder_impl_fast.InternalRow'>"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. It is a bug. I have created a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23121 to fix it. It will be fixed in the release 1.13.2